# Cannot access/unlock top panel in Ubuntu 10.04 (Netbook Edition)

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, netbook, gnome-panel, ubuntu-netbook-remix

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 10.04 (Netbook Edition) on my NC10 netbook and now I can't seem to access/unlock the top panel and add/delete programs. Right clicking doesn't bring up the options to let me change things.

Any ideas?

Comment: please tag this question ubuntu-netbook-edition

Answer (score 1):

How to Unlock Gnome Panel For Customization in Ubuntu Netbook Edition (UNE)
http://maketecheasier.com/unlock-gnome-panel-in-ubuntu-netbook-edition-une/2010/04/25